# environmental variables for jetbrains IDE external tools

Tags: debugging, webstorm, external-tools

I created webstorm external tool which throws some errors but running the same task from terminal works fine.I understand that this is because when run in webstorm the $PATH variable is set different from that of the terminal case. There isn't any option to set environmental variable while creating an external tool. How do I set $PATH for external tools in webstorm/rubymine? External tool I was creating was a grunt task and OS is ubuntu if that helps.

This is the error: Error running grunt server: Cannot run program "grunt": error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-14429) to support environment variables for the external tools.

Current workarounds:

- Make GUI apps environment the same as in Terminal per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891)
- Run your script via `bash --login` (external tool runs bash login shell that sets the environment and executes the script name passed as a parameter)

Comment: thank you. you explained the issue well and i used your second solution.

Answer (score 1):

For OSX:

Open `‘/Applications/Webstorm.app/Contents/Info.plist’` in your favorite editor.

Find the following section and replace [Your Path Value]

```
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>[Your Path Value]</string>
</dict>
```

Then run:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /Applications/WebStorm.app
```

---

I got this fix from a fantastic [article](http://ify.io/getting-webstorm-external-tools-to-work-on-webstorm-on-osx) by Ifeanyi Isitor

http://ify.io/getting-webstorm-external-tools-to-work-on-webstorm-on-osx

Answer (score 0):

I've found a dirty-workarround for linux. 
Create a file (e.g phpstorm_wrapper) and put this inside:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# > 1 ]; then
  exec "$@"
else
 eval "$1"
fi
```

Save and make it executable.

**USAGE:**

Now you can run the wrapper-script as `Program:` in your "external tools" and set all Parameters you like to the `Arguments` inputfield.

The script will execute it and return the result of it.

---

If you need to **use ENV-Variable**, you must use `env` command like this:

`env FASTLANE_JSON_KEY_FILE=./release_manager.json fastlane test`

[image]

---

If you need to **use | (pipes)**, phpstorm put it in quotes. To be able to execute commands which use |, encapsulate the whole Textfield "Arguments" in the `external tool dialoge` in quotes.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some workarounds that I use on Windows until the feature is supported by IntelliJ. Please star the [feature-request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-14429)

## cross-env

In my projects, I already have [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) installed, so I can easily reuse it in the `External Tools` dialog, e.g.

- Program: `D:\dev\YOUR_PROJECT\node_modules\.bin\cross-env.cmd`
- Arguments: `MY_ENV_VAR=value MY_ENV_VAR2=1 D:\dev\SomeExe -exeOptions`

## Shell Script Workaround

**note**: with this method, the color output on the console did not work (i.e. the ansi-color codes are not interpreted)

My workaround is to use a `Shell Script` run configuration

- set `Execute` to Script text and simply start the executable (with optional args)
- here we can also set the working dir and env vars
- note: my terminal is set to git-bash: thus I must use `./` before the exe name

[image]